# Get value of key from specific JSON object in Array using Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I'm new into Python and JSON and trying some things out. However, I seem to be stranded not being able to get specific values for keys in a JSON file. Hope you can point me in the right direction.

Using an API I am able to load the data I need. In the file I need to lookup and print the number of free spots for a specific bicycle parking spot. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import json
import requests

data = requests.get("https://stallingsnet.nl/api/1/parkingcount/utrecht")

parkingData = json.loads(data.text)

for facility in parkingData:
    print(facility["facilityName"], facility["freePlaces"])
```

I can manage to print the free spots for all facilities, but how do I print the number of free spots for a specific facilityName? For example for 'facilityName': 'Stationsplein'?

I tried to add:

```
for 'facilityName' == "Stationsplein":
```

but that did not display any results.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what data.text looks like?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to transform the data to a dictionary. Then you can easily query the dictionary for specific place:

```py
import requests

parkingData = requests.get("https://stallingsnet.nl/api/1/parkingcount/utrecht").json()
data = {facility["facilityName"]: facility["freePlaces"] for facility in parkingData}

print(data.get('Stationsplein', 'N/A'))
```

Prints:

```
3933
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I also managed to get the value from a python array but yours is shorter.